# How to redirect to another component onsubmit Search?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redirect, react-router

So I'm working on an react app and I've been stuck on an issue for like two days. I'm building a search that gets data from TMDB, and all that works fine. When I type in the input all the data come flowing in! However, when I submit and try to redirect to the /results page which is linked to a component that displays the Search Results when directed to But its  redirect to result page and i can't show search result . Here is my code.

```
import React, { Component, Redirect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: [],
      term: ""
    };

    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { history } = this.props;
    if (prevState.results !== this.state.results) {
      history.push("/results");
    }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const term = e.target.elements.term.value;
    let url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv?api_key=6d9a91a4158b0a021d546ccd83d3f52e&language=en-US&query=${term}&page=1`;
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        // const info = response.data.results;
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({
          results: data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            type="text"
            name="term"
            value={this.state.term}
          />
          <button type="submit" bsStyle="primary">
            Find
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Find);
```

and `Result.js`

```
<div className="search-poster-container">
     {this.props.results.map(result => { // This error show how to reolve this
     <p>{result.name}</p>
    })} 
    <h1>Hello Result will fetch here</h1>

  </div>
```

Comment: Does the execution reach the code inside the `if` inside `componentDidUpdate`?

Answer (score 0):

In `componentDidUpdate` you’re comparing `prevState.results` to `this.state.results`, but when you fetch data you’re calling the state variable `info`. Try renaming `info` to `results` in `submit`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the route otherwise **`history.push`** will not work

And try to user **`react-router-dom`** instead

Here is my sample code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Result from "./result";

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div id="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/result" component={Result} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any props to "result" page. What will be shown on that page?
did you mean to show the data that you got from the Api call on "result" page?